# Unix script to search within a compressed .gz file

Tags: unix, shell, grep

I want to get a few lines from a file which is in a compressed .gz file.

The .gz file contains many txt files and I want to search a string in all these txt files and need to get the previous 3 line as output, including the current line (where the search string  is present).

I tried `zgrep` and got the line number, but when I use `head` or `tail` command It's giving some garbage values. I think we cannot use the `head` or `tail` commands with compressed files containing multiple files.

Please suggest if there is any simple way?

Comment: Is it possible to retitle this so that it's clear this is a .tar.gz.  Do you want the three previous lines only in one file, or is it okay if it reports a line froma previous file?

Comment: three previous lines from one file/same file

Comment: Zip files != tar-balls. Please fix the wording.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The essence of how to accomplish this is to get the names of the files within the tarball to search over, and extract their content to be searched, while not extracting anything else.  Because we don't want to write to the file system, we can use the `-O` flag to instead extract to standard-out.

`tar -tzf file.tar.gz | grep '\.txt' | xargs tar -Oxzf file.tar.gz | grep -B 3 "string-or-regex"` will concatenate all of the files in the .tar.gz with names ending in ".txt", and `grep` them for the given string, also outputting the 3 previous lines.  It won't tell you which file in the tarball any match came from, and the "three previous lines" may in fact come from the previous file.

You can instead do:

```
for file in $(tar -tzf file.tar.gz | grep '\.txt'); do 
    tar -Oxzf file.tar.gz "$file" | grep -B 3 --label="$file" -H "string-or-regex"
done
```

which will respect file boundaries, and report the file names, but be much less efficient.

(`-z` tells `tar` it is `gzip` compressed. `-t` lists the contents.  `-x` extracts.  `-O` redirects to standard output rather than the file system.  Older `tar`s may not have the `-O` or `-z` flag, and will want the flags without `-`: e.g. `tar tz file.tar.gz`)

Okay, so you have an unusable grep.  We can fix that with awk!

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { context=3; }
{ add_buffer($0) }
/pattern/ { print_buffer() }
function add_buffer(line)
{
    buffer[NR % context]=line
}
function print_buffer()
{
    for(i = max(1, NR-context+1); i <= NR; i++) {
        print buffer[i % context]
    }
}
function max(a,b)
{
    if (a > b) { return a } else { return b }
}
```

This will not coalesce adjacent matches, unlike grep -B, and can thus repeat lines that
are within 3 lines of two different matches.

Comment: Does it support -C?  Is it a problem to get 3 lines after as well?

Comment: unfortunately no C as well :(

Comment: @CFUser: Without `-B` support in `grep`, you'll have to used `awk`, `sed` or Perl to hold a moving window of lines which are output when your match is found. GNU `tar` supports `--wildcards` which makes the first `tar|grep` in each of the versions unnecessary. Other versions of `tar` may or may not support globbing and may or may not require a switch to enable it.

Comment: As long as you want GNU tar, Why not just install GNU coreutils and use gtar/ggrep? But in general, I like the awk answer =).

Answer (score 0):

Is that maybe a gzip of a tar file?  The simplest is just extract the whole thing and use the regular tools on the extracted files.

Comment: yes its gzip of a tar file. I cannot Extract, bcoz it contains Huge files and will get Disk space problems